# TWIML Schema Validation Warning

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

This block of Twiml is throwing a schema validation warning.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message> Trinethra Indian Supermarket Peacock Indian Cuisine Sneha South & North Indian </Message>
    <Message>Restaurant Peacock Indian Cuisine Indian Health Center of Santa Clara Valley Inc</Message>
    <Message>orporated</Message>
</Response>
```

I am not exactly able to make out what mistake I am making. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `<Message>` once inside `<Response>`. So do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message>Trinethra Indian Supermarket Peacock Indian Cuisine Sneha South & North Indian Restaurant Peacock Indian Cuisine Indian Health Center of Santa Clara Valley Inc orporated</Message>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which service you're trying to work with, but this section of the Twilio TwiML documentation might help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml.